# Share cookie between webrequest and webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, cookies, httpwebrequest, browser

sending the webrequest alone doesn't work, need to login, so i need to use a cookie in which i added a webbrowser to help but I don't know how to grab the cookie from the webbrowser :/

code I'm using:
http://pastebin.com/4NXjDLJp

Comment: code belongs in your question.  nobody will follow random links.  also, ask a question if you want an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.aspx

> For security reasons, cookies are disabled by default. If you want to use cookies, use the CookieContainer property to enable cookies.

You can retrieve cookies from the `HttpWebResponse.Cookies` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.cookies.aspx

**EDIT**

The problem with your code seems to be that you are always using an empty cookie container.

Didn't you mean to write this:

```
postReq.CookieContainer = loginCookie
```

instead of:

```
postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
```